# Connecting two data view web parts without defaulting to first value

Tags: data-view-web-part, connected-web-parts

I have two data view web parts on a web part page and want the user's selection of a value in the first web part to filter the second.

However, on page load the second web part is filtered as if the first item in the first web part were selected.

How do I display all items in the second web part until the user selects an item in the first?